# How does one update an array's indices after using $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I am using jQuery's `$.each` function to append (then `delete`) each item as I iterate through an array. I then use an `if` statement to stop iterating after deleting 8 objects. Here is a very simple example:

```
$.each(media, function(index, item) {
    if (index < 8) {
        $list.append(item);
        delete media[index];
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

**The problem is** if I run the code a second time, it runs eight times...but appends nothing. Here is a screenshot of from Chrome's console after the second run:

[image]

It appears as if this quirk has something to do with the fact that my indices don't re-sort/set after each time `$.each` is used. Am I missing something or is anyone aware of an elegant workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the shift function?

```
var media = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10];
var $list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $list.push(media.shift ());
}
```

or

```
var media = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10];
var $list = [];

$.each(media, function(index, item) {
    if (index < 8) {
        $list.push(media.shift());
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

returns the same thing

```
console.log(media) = [9, 10]
console.log($list) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

`delete` replaces item from array with `undefined` ; try utilizing `Array.prototype.splice()`

```
var i = 0;

do {
  var j = media.splice(0, 1);
  $list.append(j);
  ++i;
} while (i < 8);
```

---

```js
var media = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx".split("");

var $list = $("span:first");
var _media = $("span:last");

var i = 0;

do {
  var j = media.splice(0, 1);
  $list.append(j);
  ++i;
} while (i < 8);

_media.append(media);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
list: <span></span><br />
media: <span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var media_8= media.slice(0,8)
media= media.slice(8,media.length-8)
media_8.forEach(function(item) {
    $list.append(item);
});
```